# How to continue a CakePHP 3 session in a regular PHP script?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

My situation is the following. I have a cakephp project and a seperated plain php script running on the same server.
When I use my client browser to connect to the cakephp project, it builds up a session as it should.

Now I want to continue the session data with my plain php script. Again I use the same client browser to access the plain php script (so the request meta data should be the same and the session should be recognized) and I set cakephp session option to PHP.

```
'Session' => [
  'defaults' => 'php',
 ],
```

However, I cant find out how to continue the session on the plain php script.
I would have assumed the following two lines of my plain php script would do the magic:

```
session_start(); 
echo json_encode($_SESSION);
```

Kind regards,
Marius

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CakePHPs PHP session defaults (like all built-in defaults) do change the name of the cookie / the name of the session ([**`session.name`**](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name) INI setting) to `CAKEPHP`:

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.5.3/src/Network/Session.php#L133-L138**

So you either have to change that to match the defaults used by your vanilla PHP app (which is most probably `PHPSESSID`, ie the PHP default):

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => session_name(), // would use the PHP default
],
// ...
```

or change the latter app to use the name configured for your CakePHP application:

```
session_name('CAKEPHP');
session_start();
// ...
```

Also make sure that the [**`session.cookie_path`**](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path) and [**`session.cookie_domain`**](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) configuration covers both of your applications locations.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Sessions > Session Configuration](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#session-configuration)**
- **[Cookbook > Sessions > Setting ini directives](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#setting-ini-directives)**